# Proof of the inequality $(x+y)^n\leq 2^{n-1}(x^n+y^n)$

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis

Can you help me to prove that
$$(x+y)^n\leq 2^{n-1}(x^n+y^n)$$
for $n\ge1$ and $x,y\ge0$.

I tried by induction, but I didn't get a result.

Comment: Are there additional restrictions? As in numbers being non-negative?

Comment: there is a missing condition $x=0,y=-1,n=3$ gives $-1\leq -4$ which is false.

Comment: aa, yes, sorry. $n\geq 1$ and $x,y\geq 0$

Comment: What is true is $|x+y|^n\leq 2^{n-1}(|x|^n+|y|^n)$. 
That's Hölder in $\mathbb{C}^2$: $|(u,v)|\leq \|u\|_p\|v\|_q$ with $u=(1,1)$, $v=(x,y)$, $p=n$, and $q=\frac{n}{n-1}$. Of course, it can be proved directly in this special case.

Comment: Please choose more descriptive, informative titles in the future. People who are searching the site need to be able to see what a question is about from its title.

Comment: @julien Can we use that $\varphi(x)=|x|^p$ is convex function for $p \geqslant 1$, for alternative proof of your inequality?

Comment: @Cortizol My [favourite proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder's_inequality#Proof_of_H.C3.B6lder.27s_inequality) of Hölder uses [Young](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young's_inequality), which is just concavity of $\log$.

Comment: @julien Yes, I also learned that proof (except that we used concavity of $\log$ on Analysis II, and convex of $\exp$ on Real Analysis (which is part of Analysis III on my faculty)). But my way only use "standard" definition of convex function $f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) \leq \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda) f(y)$, for $\lambda = 1/2$.

Comment: @Cortizol In this special case, indeed, this is just the midpoint convexity of $f(t)=t^n$.

Comment: @user23709 I've edited your post to add the condition you have given in the comment. In general it is better if you write your post so that it contains all necessary information and the readers and answers don't have to check comments for additional information. Please check whether some further clarifications are needed. (If you assume $n$ to be an integer, you should explicitly say so. You might also mention where you have encountered the problem.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Thanks; I was about to do the same. The restriction on $x,y\ge0$ is not needed for $n$ even, but induction fails, unless you handle $n$ even separately. However, Jensen works for even $n$ and all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look. I also have tried to do it by induction. It is obvious that it holds for $n=1$ and $n=2$. Assume that it also holds for $n$. Let's prove that inequality for $n+1$:
$$
2^n(x^{n+1} + y^{n+1}) - (x+y)^{n+1} = 2^{n}(x^{n+1} + y^{n+1}) -(x+y)^n(x+y)\geq 2^n(x^{n+1} + y^{n+1}) - 2^{n-1}(x^n + y^n)(x+y) = 
2^{n-1}(x^{n+1} + y^{n+1} - x^ny - y^nx) = 2^{n-1}(y(y^n - x^n) + x(x^n - y^n))=
2^{n-1}(y^n-x^n)(y-x) = 2^{n-1}(y-x)^2(y^{n-1}+xy^{n-2}+x^2y^{n-2}+\dots+y^2x^{n-2} + x^{n-1}) \geq 0. 
$$ 
So we have proved that $2^n(x^{n+1} + y^{n+1}) - (x+y)^{n+1} \geq 0$. It is similar to $(x+y)^{n+1} \leq 2^n(x^{n+1} + y^{n+1})$

Comment: Thanks to everyone. Can you tell me does this problem has anything with convex functions? Because I got to do that problem after lesson in convex functions.

Comment: I think it is very probable. Because only for convex function inequality $$ f\left(\frac{x + y}{2}\right) \leq \frac{f(x) + f(y)}{2} $$ is true. In this case $f(x) = x^n$. So we have just proved that $f = x^n$ is convex.

Comment: @mechanician: are you sure that the converse of Jensen inequality is also true?

Comment: Why not? There is a statement "if and only if" about function convexity and this inequality.

Comment: @mechanician: As Mark Bennet notes in his answer, $(y^n-x^n)(y-x)\ge0$ by checking both cases $y\ge x$ and $y\lt x$. However, your method using the factorization of $y^n-x^n$ is also neat. (+1)

Comment: @mechanician How does the powers of $x$ and $y$ change in factorisation you used? Are they ok in what you wrote?

Comment: Emm... I did not understand the question... I have used identical relation. Sum in braces we can write as $$ \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}y^{n-1-k}x^k $$

Answer (score 10):

**Using Jensen's Inequality**

This is simply [Jensen's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) applied to the convex function $x^n$ for $n\ge1$ and a discrete measure. In fact, this can be generalized to any non-negative sequence $(\alpha_i)$ so that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^k\alpha_i=1
$$
to get
$$
\left(\sum_{i=1}^k\alpha_ix_i\right)^n\le\sum_{i=1}^k\alpha_ix_i^n
$$
In this particular case, $k=2$ and
$$
(\alpha_i)=\left(\frac12,\frac12\right)
$$
yields
$$
\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)^n\le\frac{x^n+y^n}{2}
$$
which is the same as
$$
(x+y)^n\le2^{n-1}(x^n+y^n)
$$

---

**Using the AM-GM Inequality**

Note that the [AM-GM Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) applied to $\{\overbrace{x^n,x^n,\dots,x^n}^{k\text{ copies}},\overbrace{y^n,y^n,\dots,y^n}^{n-k\text{ copies}}\}$ yields
$$
x^ky^{n-k}\le\frac{kx^n+(n-k)y^n}{n}\tag{AM-GM}
$$
Applying this to the [Binomial Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) yields
$$
\begin{align}
(x+y)^n
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x^ky^{n-k}\\
&\le\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{kx^n+(n-k)y^n}{n}\\
&=x^n\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{k}{n}+y^n\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{n-k}{n}\\
&=x^n\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n-1}{k-1}+y^n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k}\\[6pt]
&=2^{n-1}(x^n+y^n)
\end{align}
$$

---

**Negative Values**

The inequality is true if $x,y\ge0$ or $n$ is even.  The proofs above were written assuming that $x,y\ge0$; however, $x^n$ is convex over all $\mathbb{R}$ when $n$ is even, so the Jensen proof works as is. Furthermore, if $n$ is even, changing the sign of $x$ and/or $y$ leaves the right side of $\text{(AM-GM)}$ alone (and positive), but might change the sign of the left side to be negative. In either case, $\text{(AM-GM)}$ holds for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ when $n$ is even.

Answer (score 6):

Note that the equation is equivalent to $$\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)^n\le \frac{x^n+y^n}2$$

And this can be proved by induction (with appropriate constraints to avoid multiplying an inequality by a negative number) provided $$\frac{(x^n+y^n)}2\frac{(x+y)}2\le\frac{x^{n+1}+y^{n+1}}2$$ and this reduces to $$x^{n+1}+y^{n+1}-xy^n-x^ny\ge 0$$ or $$x^n(x-y)-y^n(x-y)\ge0
$$

or $$(x^n-y^n)(x-y)\ge 0$$ And you can probably complete the details from there.

---

Note in response to comment - use the inductive hypothesis as follows:

$$\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)^{n+1}\le\frac{(x^n+y^n)}2\frac{(x+y)}2\le\frac{x^{n+1}+y^{n+1}}2$$

The first inequality comes from the hypothesis, the second will get us from $n$ to $n+1$ if we can prove it.

Comment: Where did you get this from  
$$\frac{(x^n+y^n)}2\frac{(x+y)}2\le\frac{x^{n+1}+y^{n+1}}2$$ ?  
I don't know what should I do with $(x^n-y^n)(x-y)\geq 0$ ... :/

Comment: The bit at the beginning isn't strictly necessary, if you try to prove the inequality by induction on $n$ it should become clear (after multiplying both sides by $(x + y)$)that it is sufficient to prove $x^{n+1} + y^{n+1} \geq x^ny + xy^n$.

Comment: As to proving the last inequality, you could split into two cases, $x \geq y$ or $x <y$. You could also use the factorisation $(x^n - y^n)(x-y) = (x^{n-1} + x^{n-2}y + ... xy^{n-2} + y^{n-1})(x-y)^2$, both of the factors in the latter expression are clearly positive.

Comment: @user23709 - I've added an explanation at the end

Comment: @user23709 - the two factors are both positive, both zero, or both negative - in each case the inequality holds.

Comment: Note that $\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)^n\le \frac{x^n+y^n}2$ is essentially the inequality between arithmetic and $n$-th mean.

Answer (score 0):

You've already seen approaches using estimates and induction. I want to show you another way to prove the claim that also points out where $2^{n-1}$ comes from.

Consider $g(x) = (x + y)^n - Ax^n - Ay^n$. $$g'(x) = -nAx^{n - 1} + n(x + y)^{n - 1}$$and $$g'(x_0) = 0 \Longleftrightarrow x_0 = \frac{y}{A^{1/(n - 1)} - 1}.$$
Now note that the best costant is the one that makes the minimum equal to $0$.
$$g(x_0) = 0 \Longleftrightarrow Ax_0^n + Ay^n = (x_0 + y)^n \Longleftrightarrow \frac{Ay^n}{(A^{1/(n-1)} - 1)^n} + Ay^n = \frac{A^{n/(n-1)}y^n}{(A^{1/n - 1} - 1)^n} \Longleftrightarrow Ay^n\Big(\frac{1}{(A^{1/(n - 1)} - 1)^n} + 1 - A^{n/(n - 1)}\frac{1}{(A^{1/(n - 1)^n} - 1)}\Big) \Longleftrightarrow \frac{1}{(A^{1/(n - 1)} - 1)^n} - A^{n/(n - 1)}\frac{1}{(A^{1/(n - 1)} - 1)^n} = -1 \Longleftrightarrow \frac{1}{(A^{1/(n - 1)} - 1)^n}(A^{1/(n - 1)} - 1) = 1 \Longleftrightarrow A^{1/(n - 1)} - 1 = 1 \Longleftrightarrow A = 2^{n - 1}.$$

Answer (score 0):

While we already have an array of solutions with a variety of distinct approaches, I was surprised that no one used the possibly-simplest approach of maxima.

With the non-negativity assumptions $x,y\geq0$ we may use the max-properties $\max(x,y) \leq x+y$ and $\max(x,y)^n = \max(x^n,y^n), n \in \mathbb{N}$, to obtain the following linear/calculational/motivated proof.

$
\hspace{0.5cm}2^{n-1}(x^n + y^n) \\
\geq 2^{n-1} \cdot\max(x^n,y^n) \hspace{3cm}\text{---since $x^n,y^n\geq0$} \\
= \frac{1}{2} \cdot 2^n \cdot \max(x^n,y^n) \hspace{3cm}\text{  ---arithmetic}\\
= \frac{1}{2} \cdot 2^n \cdot \max(x,y)^n \hspace{3cm}\text{  --- since $x,y,n\geq0$}\\
= \frac{1}{2} \cdot (2 \cdot \max(x,y))^n \hspace{3cm}\text{  ---powers}\\
= \frac{1}{2} \cdot (\max(x,y) +\max(x,y))^n \hspace{1.5cm}\text{  ---arithmetic}\\
\geq \frac{1}{2} \cdot (x+y)^n \hspace{2.5cm}\text{---since $x,y \leq \max(x,y)$ and non-negative powers preserve order}\\
= \frac{(x+y)^n}{2} \hspace{5cm}\text{---notation}
$

Note that we have started with the complex expression with the goal of ${\bf simplifying}$ it. As a result, we have ${\bf discovered}$, rather than $\textit{verified}$, the result!

Note that the above proof shows that the result holds for any non-negative reals $x,y$ and any integer $n\geq0$.

Indeed, motivated-discovery is better than verification.

Best regards,

Moses

EDIT :: something's gone wrong; we have an extra fraction at the end ... if anyone could explain where I've erred, I'd be most-grateful!

$\vdots$

So we proved $(x+y)^n \leq 2^n(x^n+y^n)$ and this follows from what we had to prove $\ldots$

Comment: I'm afraid the estimations $x+y \leq 2 \max(x,y)$ and $\max(x,y) \geq x,y$ lose too much, and they are the reason of extra $\frac{1}{2}$. Your proof is correct, but shows too little.

Answer (score 0):

Without loss of generality, assume that $x\geq y$. Let $\mu=\frac{x+y}{2}$ and $\delta=\frac{x-y}{2}$. The inequality is then equivalent to $2\mu^n\leq(\mu+\delta)^n+(\mu-\delta)^n$ and it holds because the RHS is equal to $$2\mu^{n}+2\binom{n}{2}\mu^{n-2}\delta^{2}+2\binom{n}{4}\mu^{n-4}\delta^{4}+\cdots++2\binom{n}{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\mu^{n-2\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\delta^{2\lfloor n/2\rfloor},$$ which is a sum of nonnegative terms.

---

*(I always visit this site using the Tor Browser. Probably due to a code change on this site, I am told by this site that "Editing is currently forbidden". I cannot edit my answer to fix any error and I cannot respond to comments. I apologize for any inconvenience caused.)*