# Upper bound of of powers of a binomial

Tags: binomial-theorem, upper-lower-bounds

I need to proof a property of an object of statistic.

I would have finished successfully if it was not for me to use an upper bound of a power of a binomial that i found in my book that I can't proof :(

$|x+y|^k ≤ 2^{k-1}(|x|^k+|y|^k)$

I've tried differents roads but unseccesfuly, my "best results" was

$2^{k-1} ≤ \frac{x^k\sum\limits_{i=1}^k{{{k}\choose{i}}\frac{y^i}{x^i}}}{x^k + y^k}$

That i can't simpplify so... Help please.

Comment: duplpicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/409604/proof-of-the-inequality-xyn-leq-2n-1xnyn

Comment: It's hard to find the answer you need if that has "proof of inequality" as its title man, aniway thanks for the answer

Comment: I searched 2^{n-1} and inequality, But I don't blame you, I find the link helpfull for you as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $k \geq 1$, $x\geq 0, y \geq 0$, Take
$$
f(x) = x^k.
$$

$f$ is convex, hence by convexity, for $0\leq t \leq 1$,
$$
f(a t + b (1-t)) \leq  f(a)t+f(b)(1-t)
$$

Now take $a=x, b=y, t=1/2$ and simplify will get
$$
(\frac{x+y}{2})^k \leq2^{-1}(x^k+y^k)
$$

Simplifying lead to the inequality. It's now not hard to extend to the case with $x,y$ possibly negative by noting $|x+y|\leq |x| + |y|$.